# Is there any way to ignore error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

Using Laravel mailable I want to send mail to my client.

But when I tried to send mail to an email that is not available or that email is not exist I got an error saying:

> Expected response code 354 but got code "554", with message "554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients "

I tried to put `try and catch` method but it doesn't work.

I also find answers from the internet but i failed.
This is my `try catch` code:

```
try {
    Mail::to($_val['email'])->send(new ClientMail($_val));
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // Do nothing 
}
```

How can I ignore the error message even if the email does not exist I want to proceed

Comment: You spelled it incorrectly, `Exeption` != `Exception` - though, generally speaking, outright ignoring errors/exceptions are a bad idea. It should be logged, trigger some message or do some action.

Comment: Do you want to teach me how to can i logged the error or i can try catch and send a session message with the error?

Comment: Laravel is well documented and has a very active community which created a ton of tutorials about every topic. I think you can figure that out by yourself and ask on stackoverflow again if you have specific problems.

Comment: You misspelled `Exception` in your code. Please try `} catch(\Exception $e) {`.